# Google Recaptcha Subresource integrity

Tags: c#, .net, filter, recaptcha, subresource-integrity

I wanted to ask if it's possible to create SRI for Google Recaptcha.
In a project, we are verifying user using filter (inheritates from `IActionFilter`, `IMvcFilter`) which calls `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=...`

Searched web for info, I found that Google doesn't share info of which version of the API the user is using, so because of that SRI id disabled for recaptcha.
But I am not 100% sure if it's true.